# Python recursion, how come my function doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a Python 3 recursive function which will tell me if an integer is in a nested list.  I am not sure how I can make my code return `True` if it finds it in the list, and `False` if it doesn't find it in the list.  When I print the result of my for loop, I get a bunch of

```
false
false
false
false
true
false
false
false
```

etc.  But, it returns False because the last call was false, even though I want it to return true.  How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
def nestedListContains(NL, target):    
    if( isinstance(NL, int) ):
        return NL    

    for i in range(0, len(NL)):
       return ( nestedListContains(NL[i], target) == target )

    return False
```

And here is how I'm calling it

```
print(nestedListContains([[3], [4,5,7], [[[8]]]], 8))
```

EDIT: This seems to be working for me, but it seems rather ghetto:

```
def nestedListContains(NL, target):    
    if( isinstance(NL, int) ):
        if( NL == target ):
            return 1
        return 0

    x = 0

    for n in NL:
        x += nestedListContains(n, target) == 1        

    return x != 0
```

Comment: Besides the recursive problem, your base case seems wrong. When you get down to an `int`, instead of returning true iff it equals the target, you return the `int` itself. That means that ultimately, you'll return true if there are any non-zero elements in the list, false otherwise.

Comment: You also might want to think about robustness here. If NL contains any non-int non-sequences, it'll raise a `TypeError`, which is probably fine—but if it contains any strings, it'll go into infinite recursion (which will eventually raise an exception when it hits the limit), which may not be fine.

Comment: Also: Why not just remove the `int` check, and just do `if NL == target: return True`? If `target` is always an `int`, this will have the exact same effect. But it allows you to search for other types (including objects that can compare equal to an `int` but aren't one). And it's simpler.

Comment: @abamert, you have to check that NL is an iterable, otherwise the `for` loop will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `return` the result regardless of whether it's `True` or not. You could do something like this:

```
def nestedListContains(NL, target):    
    if isinstance(NL, int):
        return NL == target

    for n in NL:
       result = nestedListContains(n, target)

       if result:
           return result

    return False
```

Comment: Did you mean `nestedListContains(n, target) == target`?

Comment: def nestedListContains(NL, target):    
    if( isinstance(NL, int) ):
        if( NL == target ):
            return 1
        return 0

    x = 0
    
    for n in NL:
        x += nestedListContains(n, target) == 1        
                
    return x != 0 

Your method still wasnt working for me
I am now doing things in a ghetto way, but it seems to be working, is there any alternative to this?

Comment: It won't work for nested values: nestedListContains([[9, 4, 5], [3, 8]], 3)

Answer (score 5):

My attempt:

```
def contains(lst, target):
    if isinstance(lst, int):
        return lst == target

    return any(contains(x, target) for x in lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using duck typing for @gatto's solution

```
def contains(lst, target):
    try:
        return any(contains(x, target) for x in lst)        
    except TypeError:
        return lst == target
```

Comment: Might get into infinite recursion if `lst` has a string. I think it's better to check if there is `__iter__` attribute.